# Scrape multiple URLs with Scrapy

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

How can I scrape multiple URLs with Scrapy?

Am I forced to make multiple crawlers?

```
class TravelSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "speedy"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://example.com/category/top/page-%d/" % i for i in xrange(4),"http://example.com/superurl/top/page-%d/" % i for i in xrange(55)]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        items = []
        item = TravelItem()
        item['url'] = hxs.select('//a[@class="out"]/@href').extract()
        out = "\n".join(str(e) for e in item['url']);
        print out
```

Python says:

```
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

But when I use one URL it works fine!

```
start_urls = ["http://example.com/category/top/page-%d/" % i for i in xrange(4)"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your python syntax is incorrect, try:

```
start_urls = ["http://example.com/category/top/page-%d/" % i for i in xrange(4)] + \
    ["http://example.com/superurl/top/page-%d/" % i for i in xrange(55)]
```

If you need to write code to generate start requests, you can define a [start_requests()](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.BaseSpider.start_requests) method instead of using start_urls.

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize `start_urls` in `__init__.py` method:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider


class TravelItem(Item):
    url = Field()


class TravelSpider(BaseSpider):
    def __init__(self, name=None, **kwargs):
        self.start_urls = []
        self.start_urls.extend(["http://example.com/category/top/page-%d/" % i for i in xrange(4)])
        self.start_urls.extend(["http://example.com/superurl/top/page-%d/" % i for i in xrange(55)])

        super(TravelSpider, self).__init__(name, **kwargs)

    name = "speedy"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        items = []
        item = TravelItem()
        item['url'] = hxs.select('//a[@class="out"]/@href').extract()
        out = "\n".join(str(e) for e in item['url']);
        print out
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are only four ranges in Python: `LEGB`, because the local scope of the `class` definition and the local extent of the `list derivation` are not nested functions, so they do not form the Enclosing scope.Therefore, they are two separate local scopes that cannot be accessed from each other.

**so, don't use 'for' and class variables at the same time**