# Is it possible to crawl multiple start_urls list simultaneously

Tags: python, scrapy

I have 3 URL files all of them have same structure so same spider can be used for all lists.
A special need is that all three need to be crawled simultaneously.

is it possible to crawl them simultaneously without creating multiple spiders?

I believe this answer

```
start_urls = ["http://example.com/category/top/page-%d/" % i for i in xrange(4)] + \
["http://example.com/superurl/top/page-%d/" % i for i in xrange(55)]
```

in [Scrap multiple urls with scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103938/scrap-multiple-urls-with-scrapy) only joins two list, but not to run them at the same time.

Thanks very much

Comment: You cannot. You'll need to have multiple spiders running.

Comment: What do you actually mean by "simultaneously"? This requirement is kind of vague, since I believe you don't actually need to _download_ the pages at the exact same time, so it doesn't make sense in this context. If you just want the process to run at the same-ish time, then either a single crawl with multiple start_urls, or multiple crawlers running in parallel satisfy this condition. But if your goal is to have a lower total crawling time, than you got the question all wrong.

Answer (score 1):

use start_requests instead of start_urls ... this will work for u

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'myspider'

def start_requests(self):
    for page in range(1,20):
        yield self.make_requests_from_url('https://www.example.com/page-%s' %page)
```