# Scrapy: multiple "start_urls" yield duplicated results

Tags: python, scrapy

Although my simple code seems OK according to [the official document](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html), it generates unexpectedly duplicated results such as:

- 9 rows/results when setting 3 URLs
- 4 rows/ results when setting 2 URLs

When I set just 1 URL, my code works fine. Also, I tried [the answer solution in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51869266/python-scrapy-start-urls), but it didn't solve my issue.

[Scrapy command]

```
$ scrapy crawl test -o test.csv
```

[Scrapy spider: test.py]

```
import scrapy
from ..items import TestItem

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = [
        'file:///Users/Name/Desktop/tutorial/test1.html',
        'file:///Users/Name/Desktop/tutorial/test2.html',
        'file:///Users/Name/Desktop/tutorial/test3.html',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            table_rows = response.xpath('//table/tbody/tr')

            for table_row in table_rows:
                item = TestItem()
                item['test_01'] = table_row.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract_first()
                item['test_02'] = table_row.xpath('td[2]/text()').extract_first()

                yield item
```

[Target HTML: test1.html, test2.html, test3.html]

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>test2</title> <!-- Same as the file name  -->
</head>
  <body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>test2 A1</td>　<!-- Same as the file name  -->
                <td>test2 B1</td>　<!-- Same as the file name  -->
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Generated CSV results for 3 URLs]

```
test_01,test_02
test1 A1,test1 B1
test1 A1,test1 B1
test1 A1,test1 B1
test2 A1,test2 B1
test2 A1,test2 B1
test2 A1,test2 B1
test3 A1,test3 B1
test3 A1,test3 B1
test3 A1,test3 B1
```

[Expected results for 3 URLs]

```
test_01,test_02
test1 A1,test1 B1
test2 A1,test2 B1
test3 A1,test3 B1
```

[Generated CSV results for 2 URLs]

```
test_01,test_02
test1 A1,test1 B1
test1 A1,test1 B1
test2 A1,test2 B1
test2 A1,test2 B1
```

[Expected results for 2 URLs]

```
test_01,test_02
test1 A1,test1 B1
test2 A1,test2 B1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating again the `start_urls`, you don't need to to that, scrapy already does it for you, so now you are looping twice on the `start_urls`.

Try that instead:

```
import scrapy
from ..items import TestItem

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = [
        'file:///Users/Name/Desktop/tutorial/test1.html',
        'file:///Users/Name/Desktop/tutorial/test2.html',
        'file:///Users/Name/Desktop/tutorial/test3.html',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        table_rows = response.xpath('//table/tbody/tr')

        for table_row in table_rows:
            item = TestItem()
            item['test_01'] = table_row.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract_first()
            item['test_02'] = table_row.xpath('td[2]/text()').extract_first()

            yield item
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Guillaume! How stupid I was! I realized that I overlooked that unnecessary "for" statement. I stayed focused only on start_urls or start_requests method instead.